# React Native + react-native-router-flux: Why is background color white during transition?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have two scenes, Login and Home, and background color for both are set to black. But during transition, when unmounting and mounting, seems like there is another background which is white.

Is there a way to figure out what that background is and change the color to black as well?

Here is my set up:

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterWithRedux>
              <Scene key='root'>
                <Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' sceneStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} title='Login'/>
                <Scene component={Home} direction='vertical' key='Home' sceneStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} title='Home'/>
              </Scene>
            </RouterWithRedux>
          </Provider>
        )
      }
    }
```

And image of transition with white showing, kind of hard to see but if you see the battery icon upper right, there is white space to the right and on top of the Login scene going down (as from Login to Home, and Login was in the process of being unmounted so was translucent black):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pass a function to the `getSceneStyle` which returns a style or `StyleSheet` object.

```
// ..
const getSceneStyle = (/* NavigationSceneRendererProps */ props, computedProps) => {
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  };
  return style;
};
// ..
<RouterWithRedux getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle}>
// ..
```

Don't do the below, just pass the prop straight to `RouterWithRedux`, `connect` will pass it through to the `Router` component:

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(<Router sceneStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>)
```